# Using Entity framework, just to compile linq to sql

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq, entity-framework

I am using entity framework  in order to have linq to sql capabilities, the query will run in other framework.
Everything is working fine except that the entity framework connect to the database and there for I get some delay.
Since I just need the generated sql query, there is not point letting entity framework to connect to the db, it is definitely overhead.
Is there anyway to compile the query without connecting to the db?

```
public class Customer
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public int Status { get; set; }
    }

    public class CustomerContext : DbContext
    {
        public CustomerContext() : base() { }
        public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
    }
```

the usage:

```
// here is the place when the db connection happens.
    using (var db = new CustomerContext())
       {
           var items = db.Customers.Where(o => (o.FirstName == "test" && o.Status > 1));
           Trace.WriteLine(items.ToString());
       }
```

Comment: Why don't you just write the queries in SQL to begin with?  Linq is much more limited in its SQL generation capabilities.

Comment: LinqToSql doesn't require EF to work, leave EF out of it if you aren't intending to use it.

Comment: @DStanley, that's a subjective opinion that not everyone would agree with...

Comment: @PinnyM - can you please explain how can it be done?

Comment: @PinnyM Which part?  Linq IS limited in its SQL generation - there are MANY things that can be done in SQL that can't be done in Linq-to-Entities.

Comment: @PinnyM I don't think the question is about the "Ling-to-SQL" framework, but generation SQL from Linq queries (currently using EF)

Comment: What are you attempting to accomplish by getting the generated SQL?

Comment: @Andrew Running the query in another framework, I want to write strong typed queries, so I just want to generate the sql in runtime and use it via other framework.